# C# Speech Recognition from wav file, I need to get time of each word - lipsync

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, wav, timespan

I already build a solution for speech recognition from a wav file and break the words apart for lipsync application, what i need from speech recognition system is words + its timing withing the wav file. I need to get the timing of every word even character (letter) any type of timing will work it can't be done under "`SpeechRecognizedEventArgs`" event I tried "`SpeechDetected`" it return the start of detection , might work. I tried:

```
static void recognizer_SpeechDetected(object sender, SpeechDetectedEventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine("  Speech detected at AudioPosition = {0}", e.AudioPosition);
// TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 01);
// Console.WriteLine(interval.ToString())
}
```

I'm getting just some millisec before audio starts.

AudioPosition inside recoginzed event giving me the full time of the wav file .

What I'm think about I need something like a loop `"foreach"` to get timing if there isn't other way to get it with recognized event with words, or 2nd option is to play wav file like 2 sec and recognize a word or half then complete. Its all about getting some kind of timing .

Maybe all of those are complex ideas cause i don't know C#.

Answer (score -1):

If your not looking to code the whole thing yourself, this company offers a product which does what you describe:

http://www.freakngenius.com/

If you do want to make your own solution, then one idea might be to look at the volume of the audio at different points. A drop in the volume would probably indicate a break between words.